# Strings matching/containing using regex android

Tags: java, android

I want to match 2 strings

e.g. I have pre-defined words like wheat, egg, flour etc...

I got the text from OCR like wh3at, agg, f1Our etc...

So **wh3at** should match **wheat** OR **f1Our** should match **flour** etc..

Comment: I dont think regex will be of any help here. looks like a machine learning problem

Comment: If you have the list of wheat, flour, egg, etc beforehand, then for each of the work got from OCR you could the edit distance for the words in the list. the word with minimum edit distance should be the match.

Comment: If you have any solution(code base) with Levenshtein distance for a huge set of data, please share

Comment: Do you have the data set to which the input words(the ones generated by OCR) will be mapped to?

Comment: Also which OCR library are you using? The google vision library works pretty well, in my knowledge.

Comment: I am using google vision sdk. Btw Thanks for your help I got the solution (code base).
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on OCR projects where we "normalized" extracted text. You can build regular expressions that match reasonably expected/observed output.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strings = {"wh3at", "f1Our", "f10ur", "agg"};

        for (String s : strings) 
            System.out.println(String.format("%s -> %s", s, normalizeWord(s)));
    }

    public static String normalizeWord(String unnormalized) {

        if (Pattern.compile("(?i)wh(e|3)at").matcher(unnormalized).matches()) {
            return "wheat";
        } else if (Pattern.compile("(?i)f(1|L)(O|0)ur").matcher(unnormalized).matches()) {
            return "flour";
        } else if (Pattern.compile("(?i)(a|e)gg").matcher(unnormalized).matches()) {
            return "egg";
        }
        return unnormalized;
    }
}
```

Comment: The piece of code you have written is for limited set of data, what if I have hundreds or thousands of pre-defined white-listed data and OCR scans a lot of text. I have seen Levenshtein distance algorithm but I am unable to implement it in my code. It would be grateful If you could share other solution.